# Probability of winning lottery

Tags: probability

In our pool league....the bottom four teams will have a random draw to pick two of the teams to advance to playoffs.

My first instinct was if $\frac{2}{4}$ teams will get picked then hey....my team has a $50%$ chance of getting in, but as we were discussing different ways of doing the drawing I realized the it may not be $50%$.  I was thinking if $4$ names go into the hat and one name is picked then one more name of the remaining $3$ names is picked then the probably for the first drawing would be $\frac{1}{4}$ and for the second drawing $\frac{1}{3}$.

If I add these together to give myself an overall probability then it would add to $\frac{7}{12}$ or about $58%$.  It just seems really odd to me that I would have a $58%$ chance in this scenario when $\frac{2}{4}$ teams are picked. So am I correct in my math or am I computing something wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the chance of being the first drawn is $\frac 14$.  To be the second drawn you need to not be the first drawn, which is a chance of $\frac 34$.  Then you have $\frac 13$ chance of being drawn, so the chance of being second drawn is $\frac 34 \cdot \frac 13=\frac 14$.  The total of these is $\frac 12$ as it should be.  Just by symmetry, it should be clear that the chance to be drawn at any position is equal.  This computation supports that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $4$ people and you choose $2$, you get $${4\choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$$ Amount of ways.

$3$ of those ways give you a chance to get in, giving you $$ \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2} = \boxed{50\%}$$

Yes, we got the same answer, but your answer would be wrong if we had different numbers. For example, what if we had $6$ teams? Try that yourself :D

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance....what type of method are you using to solve here?(I am not familiar with the exclamation points and would like to look it up)   Also you mention that there are three ways to get chosen...please explain the three ways....I would think there would only be 2 ways to get picked.....either on the first pick or on the second pick.  Thanks!

Comment: The exclamation point thing is called a factorial. The two giant bracket things are what you call choosing, and you use factorials in the formula. More on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination. Also, the three ways would be (If you were team A and the rest were BCD), AB, AC, and AD.